# Return data from rest call

Tags: angular, angular2-components

In a component I have the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.localEventEdit = this.getLocalEvent(+params['id'])
        console.log(this.localEventEdit)
    });
}

getLocalEvent(localEventId: number) {

    this.restCall.get("/localevents/" + localEventId, (data) => {
        this.localEventEdit = data;
    });
    return {name: "asdasd", languageId: 1, locationId: 1};
}
```

I want to return the data from the restCall inside `getLocalEvent` to the `this.localEventEdit` variable in `ngOnInit`.

This is the `restCall.get`:

```
//HTTP GET Request
//Default return type is JSON
public get(path: string, callback: (data) => void, returnType: number = RestCall.RETURN_TYPE_JSON) {
    this.auth.retrieveToken(path).subscribe(
        tokenResponse => {
            this.http.get(this.location + path, this.getRequestOptions(returnType))
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    return this.handleResponse(res, returnType);
                }).subscribe(
                    data => callback(data),
                    error => this.handleError(error)
                )
        },
        tokenError => this.handleError(tokenError)
    );
}
```

Any ideas? At this point I can only return `return {name: "asdasd", languageId: 1, locationId: 1};` but I want to return the data from the restcall.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return an asynchronous value in a synchronous way. The recommended way is to use observables and the async-pipe like the following:

**component.ts**

```
localEventEdit$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
   const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id']; 
   this.localEventEdit$ = this.getLocalEvent(+id);
}

getLocalEvent(localEventId: number): Observable<any> {
   return this.restCall.get("/localevents/" + localEventId);
}
```

**service.ts**

```
get(path: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.location + path;
    return this.auth.retrieveToken(path) // is it right that you don't use the token???
       .switchMap(tokenResponse => this.http.get(url, this.getRequestOptions(returnType))
       .map((res: Response) => this.handleResponse(res, returnType));
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div>{{ localEventEdit$ | async | json }}</div>
```

The async pipe will automatically manage the subscription for you.